# How to check remaining days of trial in Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, trial-version

I want to check my remaining days with office 365 trial version. 
As I want to backup my work done into it and am not finding any link or any option there.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly refer below link to check subscription of Office 365.

[Cancel your free trial of Office 365 Home](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Cancel-your-free-trial-of-Office-365-Home-6334375a-a4ac-4047-9d6c-26c278a79a4e)

Comment: Did you got remaining subscription days?